# How do I apply a calculated column to new items only?

Tags: calculated-column

I have a formula in a column that calculates the target date of + 3 months.  I want to change the formula to +9 months but only for new items.  How do I add this to the formula?

> =IF([Type of MOC]="Permanent",(IF([Actual Implementation
>   Date]="","",DATE(YEAR([Actual Implementation Date])+0,MONTH([Actual
>   Implementation Date])+9,DAY([Actual Implementation Date])+0))),"")

Answer (score 3):

I think that the only way to do this is to add a test to your formula that says "if this item is older than [Date], then use 3m else use 9m".

BTW, I'm not sure that your formula is going to work the way you want it to when you get to months >= 4. It looks like you will then get month 13.

Answer (score 2):

How long is an item considered new for?

You could create a custom column (Age) that defaults to a value "NEW" and then test that in your calculated column to decide whether to set to 9 months.

You would then need to either manually or with a workflow, change the column Age to "OLD" and you calculated column would set these to 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to apply a calculation to new items only.
According to [How Are a SharePoint List’s Calculated Columns Stored and Rendered?](http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/04/how-are-a-sharepoint-lists-calculated-columns-stored-and-rendered/) the calculation will be evaluated on every save of an item or when the calculation is changed.

For more help on calculated columns see the series [taming the elusive calculated column](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Search/results.aspx?k=taming%20the%20elusive%20calculated%20column) by Dessie Lunsford on EndUserSharePoint.com